# How to open gmail message links in Gmail Android app?

Tags: gmail

Suppose I have a link in some app of:

https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?search=query&view=tl&q=braun#inbox/158c682e555e391aJ

When I click on the link, the Android system launches the default browser and opens up Gmail. However, the browser does not open up on the specific email thread but instead opens up the Primary message view.

How do I associate these specific links with the Gmail Android app, and also arrange it so that when I click on those links that it opens up that specific message thread?

Comment: Google Tasks does this.  I asked about that in this question. https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/221922/how-does-google-tasks-open-an-email-in-the-gmail-app